# Order a table when knowing the previous ID element

Tags: php, sql

I am looking for an easy solution to order a SQL table. Here is the structure:

```
ID    | content | previous
------+---------+---------
12753 | blabla1 |
24985 | blabla2 |
31689 | blabla3 |
41036 | blabla4 | 12753
54985 | blabla5 |
```

The `previous` column is used to indicate the element that must appear just before this item. For example, I would like to have this result:

```
ID    | content | previous
------+---------+---------
12753 | blabla1 |
41036 | blabla4 | 12753
24985 | blabla2 |
31689 | blabla3 |
54985 | blabla5 |
```

Is there an easy solution with SQL? I thought I could use PHP to change the position in the array, but I think it is too complicated...

In a second step, I would like to be able to indicate that an element must be first. This element would be "0" in the `previous` column. But for this case, the simplest solution seems to me to be the PHP for that.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Regards

Comment: Could you out of curiosity do something like this `select t1.ID,
           t1.content,
           t1.previous
    from YourTable t1
           left join YourTable t2 on t1.ID = t2.Previous
    order by t1.ID, t2.Previous`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method that works for *one* level:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(previous, id), id;
```

Comment: @ThomasDiot - If the value in your `previous` column is empty string and not `NULL`, then you can do: `ORDER BY COALESCE(IIF(previous = '', NULL, previous), ID),ID`

Comment: @Brien . . . A reasonable point but a highly unlikely situation.  The ids look numeric and numeric ids are usually stored as numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks for pointing that out. As I was trying to produce an answer to the question I had made the quick mistake of just inputting the values as literal strings and then my results needed to be replaced where empty string. You make a great point, appreciate the follow up on it.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much for your answer. I tried the code you gave me, and it does'nt work completely. I exported the exact structure of my database in a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c4a8d/1
It works well for the first element with a 0 in the previous column. But then, the other elements are not sorted well... Maybe is it because ID and previous are string elements ?
Thanks again !

Comment: @ThomasDiot . . . That is what the first sentence says:  This will work for *one* level, which is what your question describes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, now I understand this sentence ! The example in my question was bad, sorry ! Any idea how I could do this with multi level ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ThomasDiot . . . MySQL has basically no support for hierarchical queries or recursive CTEs.  If you have a fixed depth, you can keep adding `join`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks ! I managed to do it witha loop in PHP !

Comment: @ThomasDiot . . . Sadly, with MySQL pre-8.0, you don't have many options.

Answer (score 0):

Glue the two id's together and use them to order. The `IF(...)` is there when you use zero as standard value in previous

```
select *
from test
order by concat(IF(previous=0,"",previous), id), id;
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/860e2/1)

Comment: Hi @Michel ! Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your code [in a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6af1fa/1), with the exact structure of my database, but it doesn't work perfectly... 
Any idea why ? Thanks again !